# Python string issue

Tags: python, string

This is to take text from a file and combine with a string to print to a new file for a combined result

```
file = open('/home/user/facts', 'r')
result = open('/home/user/result.txt', 'a')
i = 1
for line in file:
    print >>result, "fact_text[%d] = \"%s\";"% (i, line)
    i += 1
```

For some reason the `";` is showing up on a separate line, and I do not know why. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When reading lines from a file using `for line in file` the resulting string contains a newline character. You can strip it off using `line.strip()`. So your print statement becomes:

```
print >>result, "fact_text[%d] = \"%s\";" % (i, line.strip())
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `line` contains a newline character at the end.  You could trim it by doing line[:-1] or -2, depending on if you have DOS or Unix line endings